# Poweredge 2900 Failed to boot utility partition

Tags: dell-poweredge, utilities

- How to (re)install utility partition for a Dell Poweredge 2900?
- Where is installed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you already have an image of the utility partition, you don't/can't reinstall or recover it.

However, everything on the utility partition is available for download from Dell, so you'd download the diagnostics tools/utility you're looking for from their support site - [this is the page for the PE2900](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/poweredge-2900) - burn it to disk and boot from that instead.

Comment: that utility is for Windows?

Comment: @rkmax Depends what utility you're talking about.  Their diagnostic utilities usually boot into their own environment, whereas their management utilities generally have Linux and Windows versions available.